# Is "vicepraesidens" valid for "vice president"?

Tags: prefix, vocabulary, occupation, nuntii-latini

This phrase appeared in [Nuntii Latini last December](http://areena.yle.fi/1-3790762):

> *In causa erant discordiae inter praesidentem et vicepraesidentem ortae.*

Is *vice-* a good prefix in Latin, and does it really produce the same effect as in English?
That is, is *vicepraesidens* a good Latin translation of "vice president"?
Is there any precedent for using *vice-* like this?
I had not seen it before, and it feels a little off to me.

I don't think the prefix *vice-* was used with any title in the Roman system, but perhaps it was introduced later on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's Late Latin. From the OED:

> Originally this governed a following word in the genitive, but in late Latin the tendency to use the phrase as a compound noun appears in vicequæstor (equivalent to prōquæstor of analogous origin). In medieval Latin such formations became common, as vicecomes, -consul, -decanus, -dominus, -princeps, -rector, -rex, etc.

As it mentions, *pro* was the more accepted prefix, though like *vice-* was also originally a preposition. The noun phrase later become codified and the preposition became a prefix. Examples: [proconsul](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic+letter%3DP%3Aentry+group%3D105%3Aentry%3Dproconsul), [propraetor](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic+letter%3DP%3Aentry+group%3D114%3Aentry%3Dpropraetor), [propraefectus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic+letter%3DP%3Aentry+group%3D114%3Aentry%3Dpropraefectus), [proflamen](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic+letter%3DP%3Aentry+group%3D107%3Aentry%3Dproflamen), [pro quaestore](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic+letter%3DP%3Aentry+group%3D114%3Aentry%3Dproquaestore).

I don't know of any Classical Latin titles with the prefix, and Lewis and Short record none under their definition of [vicis](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic+letter%3DV%3Aentry+group%3D17%3Aentry%3Dvicis).

My understanding is that the modern spoken Latin community doesn't like archaicisms like using *consul* for *president*, so they opt for Anglicized words. The ancients sometimes did that, but from what I read, they mostly did not. Considering the presidency was partially modeled after the consulship, I think a rendering of it as *consul maior* and *consul minor* would have made sense to a Roman audience, even if it's somewhat inaccurate.

Comment: Was *pro* originally a pronoun? I can't seem to find a source for it.

Comment: @Anonym No, not at all. An exhausted brain wrote pronoun but meant preposition. Fixed, and thanks for the catch.

Comment: For what it's worth, Lewis & Short lists it as perhaps originally being ablative, with *prae* being the locative. So it could've come from a noun, if not a pronoun.

Comment: But _proconsul_, for instance, is not what we would think of when we say vice-consul. A _proconsul_ (or _propraetor_, etc) was a person (usually an _ex-_ consul, praetor, etc) who was appointed _instead_ of a properly elected magistrate. Vice-magistrates (except for a viceroy) aren't appointed "instead" of their ordinary counterparts.

Comment: Question: does the OED say it was a preposition? It looked more like dative/ablative of [vicis](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dvicis) to me.